# Adding items to array for primeng dropdown does not update the rendred dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to add a new item to a angular dropdown.

```
export class ClansOfCaledoniaComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedGame: ClansGame;
  public games = new Array<ClansGame>();

  constructor(private readonly clansOfCaledoniaService: ClansOfCaledoniaService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clansOfCaledoniaService.getListOfGames().subscribe(r => {
      this.games = r;
      this.selectedGame = this.games[0];
    });
  }
  newGame() {
    var game = new ClansGame();
    game.name = `Game ${this.games.length + 1}`;
    let p = new Array<ClansPlayer>();
    p.push(new ClansPlayer());
    game.players = p;
    this.clansOfCaledoniaService.save(game).subscribe(a => {
      game.id = +a.status;
      this.games.push(game);
      this.selectedGame = game;
      console.log(game);
    });
  }
}
```

The HTMl I'm using

```
  <div class="ui-g-2">
    <p-dropdown [options]="games" [(ngModel)]="selectedGame" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-2">
    <button pButton type="button" label="New game" (click)="newGame()"></button>
  </div>
```

For some reason the dropdown is not updated when I push the new game. How can I update the array ?

Comment: Maybe your subscription in the onInit "getListOfGames()" fires again when you call the `save` function in the `newGame()`, thus resetting your games property?

Comment: No, thats not it

Comment: Does the initial values work fine in the drop-down (before adding a new game)? If yes, can you log the `r` value in the onInit, as well as the `game` you try to push and show us the result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TIL that you have to **replace** arrays and all non-primitive types in order to trigger the binding mechanisms of Angular (coming from WPF and still shaking my head ;) ). So, instead of pushing to your array, just replace it and it should work:

```
this.clansOfCaledoniaService.save(game).subscribe(a => {
  game.id = +a.status;
  this.games = [...this.games, game];
  this.selectedGame = game;
  console.log(game);
});
```

Don't use the hack by accessing your template and updating the binding manually.

Answer (score 3):

Check this StackBlitz: [Dropdown example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfbp9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML file:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="games" [(ngModel)]="selectedGame" optionLabel="name" #acc></p-dropdown>

<button pButton type="button" label="New game" (click)="newGame(acc)</button>
```

TS file:

```
interface Game {
    name: string;
}

export class AppComponent  {
  games: Game [];
  selectedGame: Game;

  constructor() {
     this.games = [
            {name:'Game1'},
            {name:'Game2'},
            {name:'Game3'}
        ];
  }

  newGame(acc) {
    let newGame: Game = { name: "NEW GAME" };

    this.games.push(newGame);

    acc.options = this.games;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is #acc and acc.options?

Comment: The #acc is a 'template reference variable' check this in the Angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-). So acc is a reference to the dropdown element, therefore acc.options is only an access to the 'options' property of the primeng dropdown element, you can check all of the properties here (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown).